# Pass a js variable in to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, var

I am trying to pass a simple .js variable (prodID) into a jquery function that preselects a dropdown. I know the prodID variable has a value because document.write prints it out. I know that the jQuery works, because when I assign an arbitrary value (say....225)  to the 'value =' variable, the dropdown selects as it should. I just can't get value='prod_id' to work. Is always null. What am I doing wrong?

```
    var ProductID = "ProductID";
    var prodID = getCookieValue(ProductID);
    document.write(prodID);

    changeDropDown(prodID); 

    function changeDropDown(prodID){
        jQuery("#groupsel_0 option[value= 'prodID' ]").prop("selected", true);
        jQuery('#groupsel_0').trigger('change');  
    };
```

I have tried not wrapping in a function too.

Comment: Maybe jQuery("#groupsel_0 option[value= "+prodID+" ]").prop("selected", true);
?

Comment: Insert it into the string the same way you would insert any other javascript variable into a string. `"foo" + myvar + "bar"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function changeDropDown(prodID){
    jQuery("#groupsel_0 option[value= '" + prodID + "']").prop("selected", true);
    jQuery('#groupsel_0').trigger('change');  
};
```

you need to escape your string